# Showing Custom ListView Dialog as the infoWindow of Map Marker is tapped

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, google-maps-api-2, customdialog

I was able to link the infoWindow of the Map Marker to a TextView activity. When infoWindow is tapped, a textView activity appears. So, I want to try it to link to a ListView Custom Dialog. So far I'm not getting any progress because every time the I try to tap the infoWindow, the program terminates. I found no warnings in my code though. Probably the codes are still lacking. Will someone help me? I'm just doing self study here.

I have this from the MainActivity, this is for the click event of the infoWindow

```
    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker adminmarker){
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.cmumap.ADMIN");
    startActivity(intent);
    }
    });
```

I have this for the AdminActivity, this is for the Custom Dialog

```
    package com.android.cmumap;

    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

    public class AdminActivity extends DialogFragment{

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.layers)
           .setItems(R.array.layer_options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // The 'which' argument contains the index position
               // of the selected item
           }
    });
    return builder.create();
    }
    }
```

And I have this for the adminactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/layers"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/layers" />

<ListView android:id="@+id/layer_options"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:divider="#000000"
          android:dividerHeight="1dp"
          android:paddingLeft="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please tell me what is lacking.. I'm not able to do this on my own..

Comment: where is  your activity? which you want to open

Comment: the second one.. Admin Activity.. the first one I just took that part from the MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code you are exted dialogfragment so it is not an activity. you should extend **Activity** for that.

```
public class AdminActivity extends Activity{

        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.layers)
               .setItems(R.array.layer_options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                   // of the selected item
               }
        });
        return builder.create();
        }
        }
```

and in your main acitivity do this

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker adminmarker){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AdminActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
    });
```

and in you AdminActivity class just override OnCreateMethod and call onCreateDialog function from that (so your admin activity has two method onCreateDialog and onCreate).

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Dialog dialog=onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity()); getActivity() is undefined..

Comment: the Activity is blank.. :(

Comment: and yes dont forget to register your AdminActivity into AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: as I tapped the infoWindow, it goes to a black screen.. nothing in it.. i don't know why, maybe there's a problem with the xml?

Comment: where should i insert it? after public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)?